# Ranger : Open with vim in new window

Tags: vim, ranger

Using : st, Ranger, vim, i3

With most files when I open them with ranger it opens in a new window. However, when I try to open a file with vim it opens it in the current terminal which is currently running ranger.

I understand why it does it, I'm just not finding how to get the desired outcome of opening files with vim (from ranger) in a new terminal.

Comment: See [Ranger - open_with without suspending](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356732).

Answer (score 6):

You can edit ranger's rifle config for that. Rifle is ranger's file opener.

```
ranger --copy-config=rifle.conf
```

to copy the default rifle config to **~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf**

Then change the line in rifle.conf which says

**mime ^text,  label editor = ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"** to

```
mime ^text,  label editor = nohup termite -e "${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} $@" >/dev/null &
```

I use **termite** terminal emulator. Change that to **st** in your case.

To open multiple files at once you can use

```
  mime ^text,  label editor = OPEN_WITH_TABS="${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -p $@" && nohup termite -e "${OPEN_WITH_TABS}" >/dev/null &
```

Comment: I had to remove the quotes to get this to work, so my rifle.conf looks like:
mime ^text,  label editor = nohup termite -e ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} $@ >/dev/null &

Answer (score 3):

You can use `t` flag to open in a new terminal.

Use `r` shortcut or type `:open_with vim t`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution spotted by [Yash](https://superuser.com/users/994816/yash) for opening mpv in seperate window

`mime ^audio|ogg$, terminal, has mpv = nohup gnome-terminal -e "mpv '$a'" > /dev/null &`

very useful

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding your preferred terminal, you can simply set the `t` flag. This will "run [the] program in a separate terminal, as specified by $TERMCMD" (from the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rifle.1)).

This is the relevant section of my `rifle.conf`:

```
# Define the "editor" for text files as first action
mime ^text,  label editor, flag t = ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"
mime ^text,  label pager, flag t  = "$PAGER" -- "$@"
!mime ^text, label editor, ext xml|json|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|js|sh|php, flag t = ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"
!mime ^text, label pager,  ext xml|json|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|js|sh|php, flag t = "$PAGER" -- "$@"
```

Comment: The right answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the first solution didn't work on me because of quotations as @Javanator mentioned , and because `-e` option will be deprecated  in the feature here is my solution inspired by @Yash:

`mime ^text, label editor = gnome-terminal  -- vim  "$@"`

Also bonus points for adding `--geometry 153x40-0`  option after `gnome-terminal` to open vim on specific location with specific size and `--quiet` to ensure what `nohup` does.